# Please help me understand why my intuition is wrong on this basic conditional combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics

Assume there is a bag with six white balls and four red balls. What is the chance that you will select (without replacement) two white balls and a red ball given that two white balls are selected.

The answer to this question is 3/4. I understand how to get there. There are 60 different ways to draw two white balls and one red ball and 20 different ways to draw three white balls. Therefore the chance of selecting two white balls and one red ball given that two white balls are selected is 60/(60+20)=3/4.

However, when I looked at this problem I thought that the answer was very obviously 1/2. Given that two white balls are selected we have four white balls and four red balls left in the bag. The chance of selecting red then is 1/2. But this logic is incorrect. Can anyone help me understand why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are four possibilities:

- WWR
- WRW
- RWW
- WWW

The four possibilities has a probability of $\frac6{10}\cdot\frac59\cdot\frac48=\frac16$ each, that is, they are equiprobable. Then the probability that one of the balls is red given that the other two are white is $3/4$.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing states that the white balls need to be selected on first and second draws.